# Instagram API - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: arrays, api, callback, jsonp, instagram

I'm trying to learn apis and i thought that using the instagram  api would be a good learning test. I made an ajax call that loops through my images and puts them in an image tag. Some reason i get this uncaught TypeError when i go to the console. When i have the code in the for loop like this for var i=0; i < response.data.length; i++ Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined shows up.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  crossDomain: 'true',
  cache: 'false',
  jsonp: 'jsonpcallback',
  async: 'false',
  url:'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/202156622/media/recent?callback=?',
  success: function(response) {
    var familyPhoto = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      familyPhoto += '<div class="photo">';
      familyPhoto += '<img src="' + response.data[i].images.low_resolution.url +'" alt="">';
      familyPhoto += '</div>'

    }

  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to pass access_token to server as URL parameter

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/202156622/media/recent?access_token={access_token}
```

---

Second, there are the security risks in exposing user access token in javascript

[What are the security risks in exposing facebook user access token in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005210/what-are-the-security-risks-in-exposing-facebook-user-access-token-in-javascript)

**The access token is a sensible data that must be always invisible.**

You should do that through server side (Like PHP, ASP, JSP......)

---

This is a PHP wrapper for the Instagram API, it may help you

https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API