# Instagram API - How to Setup a Proxy Server for POST Request to Follow a User

Tags: api, instagram, proxy-server

I am using the below code to let a user Follow another Instagram user. However, even though the result returns a positive success (meta.code==200), the API is still not allowing a follow.

I now understand that this is because JSONP is using script tags and GET. Is the solution to set up a proxy server? If so, can you demonstrate the code on how to do this?

Many thanks!

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    "method": "POST",

    url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/' + followID + '/relationship?access_token=' + accessToken + '&callback=callbackFunction',

    data: {action: 'follow'},/*need this to access the relationship*/
    dataType: "jsonp", 
    success: function(result){
        if (result.meta.code == 200) {
            document.getElementById(followID).innerHTML = "Requested";
            document.getElementById(followID).style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("reqID" + followID).style.display = "block";
            alert(result.data.outgoing_status;);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are the security risks in exposing user access token in javascript

[What are the security risks in exposing facebook user access token in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005210/what-are-the-security-risks-in-exposing-facebook-user-access-token-in-javascript)

**The access token is a sensible data that must be always invisible.**

You should do that through server side (Like PHP, ASP, JSP......)

---

This is a PHP wrapper for the Instagram API, it may help you

https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API